Cant change even after knowing it's harmful
Why is it difficult to change our thinking patterns/belief even after knowing that it is harmful/not helpful/eventually you will regret it ?
I don't believe it is brain/mind trying to keep us safe since you feel excited when going to a trip to a new place or doing something new.
Is it lack of will power(determination) or lack of understanding/realising what I am loosing if I don't do it ?
Since there are instance ones changes overnight or does the things being procrastinated for months immediately.
